# Rate of change optimisation

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-integration

Polonium-210 is a radioactive element whose time rate of decay is 
proportional to the quantity present at any time. A nuclear 
accident, confined to a single room of a nuclear research 
laboratory has left the room contaminated with polonium-210 which 
has a half-life of 140 days. If the initial contamination of the room 
is 5 times the amount safe for long term human exposure, how long 
should laboratory workers wait to re-enter the room to 
decontaminate it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at elemental definitions, as for example at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay,
you will see that the half-time of a radiaactive substance is the time taken for the activity of a given amount of a radioactive substance to decay to half of its initial value and that it obeys an exponential law, that is to say Q = Q0 Exp[- k t].

According to your numbers, using Q = Q0 /2 and t = 140, this gives k = log(2) / 140.

The same equation will be now used with Q0 = 5 and Q = 1 to compute the time. This leads to t = 140 log(5) / log(2) which is close to 325 days (so almost a year).

Comment: thanks so much! I get it now.

Comment: @user118035. You welcome ! I am glad if this could help you. What is important is not the result but how to arrive to it. By the way, Happy New Year !

Comment: happy new year to you too! All the best for 2014 =)